# CSS : Make to sibling divs have the same height, relative to page

Tags: html, css, height

I would like to constraint one div to take the same height as a sibling div that would have variable content. Additionally, i want both divs to have a min-height of 100% of the window's size.

Here is the JSFiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/m5q38/1/

The problem is that, i would like to use `min-height` on the divs, but this requires the parent container to have a specified height, which i can't fix. And if i use `height: 100%` on my divs, they will take the height of the window, including when the content of the `#container` div is too large for this div and would overflow.

Alternatively, if i don't use `min-height` and the `#container` div has less content, the div won't take the whole window's height :

[image: Like so]

(Here is the fiddle for this other try : http://jsfiddle.net/m5q38/3/)

Does anyone know how to solve this ?

To make simple i want :

- The Green Div to fit its content
- The Green Div to have a min height of 100% the window
- The Blue Div to have the same height of the green div.

Thanks for helping !

Comment: so you want `#container` to be 100% height?

Comment: I want it to fit its content, and having a min-height of 100%. And i want the other div to have the same height than #container. Sorry if my post wasn't very clear.

Comment: [does this look right?](http://jsfiddle.net/4n9Jp/)

Comment: Nope. If the #container's content doesn't fit in the window's height, it will be displayed outside the container. Try adding more `<br>`/text in container to see by yourself.

Comment: And i don't want the #container to have a fixed height, only a minimal height.

Comment: Just a final thought (I appreciate the longing for pure css solutions)... while ensuring your containers are minimally as tall as the window really *will* have to be JS, for your sibling elements, is there any reason you can't wrap them both in a container element that shares their respective styles? You can either layer background images and position them to be half the width, or use a gradient with abrupt stops if you just want solid colors (http://jsfiddle.net/aL7sp/).

Answer (score 2):

if you can use jquery, see this [**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/m5q38/4/) and note the commented out CSS

using jquery:

```
$( function() {
    $('#left-bg').height($('#container').height())
});
```

Setting a consistent div height is always an interesting problem.  In the past, when I've had multiple sibling div elements I generally just wrap them in on div and set each div css to `display:table-cell` and that works nicely to keep heights equal regardless of div content.

Not sure you can use that here as you have positioned elements

Comment: Thanks for your answer but it doesn't work as expected since the divs don't have the min-height to 100%. Moreover, i'm looking for a Pure CSS solution.

Comment: I tried to use `display: table` but you're right, it does not work since i want the container div to be centered on the screen.

Comment: try adjusting my fiddle by adding the min-height back - i misread your OP

Comment: Also, min-height:100% does nothing; from the perspective of the cascade,  height is an infinite property—it only exists once a screen is in place to constrain it (hence the DOM's parent element is <window>.

Comment: FYI should wrap this in a `$(window).load()` if you have images that affect the height of `#container`

Answer (score 1):

This can *only* be done with Javascript, it's a pretty common problem, and there are numerous (javascript) solutions, depending on whether you've got a generalized, site-wide dilemma or just a pair of elements that need a tweak.

If you are using jquery, this will give you a basic solution that you can complicate to your needs:

```
/* note: add both ready and resize here, via "on", that way they'll
be bound to any selectors (not just id) in place of "#element1" 
(such as ".left-column"), including those that arrive via an ajax call 
(ie. aren't present when the call is made) */
$(window).on(["ready","resize"], function() {
    var heights = [$("#element1").innerHeight(),$("#element2").innerHeight()]
    var tall_then_short = [heights[0] > heights[1] ? heights : [heights[1], heights[0]];
    $("#" + tall_then_short[0]).css("min-height", "#" + tall_then_short[1]);
});
```

But a far nicer way is to use a library with this feature as it'll tend to be more robust; personally I use Foundation 5's [Equalizer](http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/components/equalizer.html) feature.

Comment: Can you please explain why there is no pure css solution to this problem, i'm surprised there is no css hack to do this ? Thanks.

Comment: Not really, I'm not expert enough; I've just faced this problem enough to know that there is definitely no pure-css solution.  You're getting into the very guts of CSS and the way browsers process it. Basically, as I understand, for a number of reasons that are partly due to somewhat antiquated restrictions, the ability to interpret the document like this was not built into presentational languages or how browsers read them (hence the DOM). 

As for CSS, it's also logically impossible; it would defeat the cascade for CSS to double back to see what's it done in order to make the comparison.